# App starting and closing itself when i run the Eclipse Code

Tags: ios, eclipse, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, appium-ios

I am automating Mobile .app(ipa) file using Appium and Eclipse.
I have set the desired capabilities. 
When I run the code, App initiates and closes instantly.
What could be the possible reason ? Please suggest.

Comment: a crash of the app could be the issue.

Comment: and how it will be fixed ? @luk2302